# Xamarin.Android shape not drawing to activity

Tags: android, draw, shapes

Why is nothing being drawn to my activity? I'm creating a shape and then adding it to the view in the activity.cs file. Is it to do with how I give it a canvas? Or do I need to invalidate it?

The shape:

```
namespace Pong.Droid
        {
            public class PaddleDrawingAndroid : View
            {
                private readonly ShapeDrawable _shape;

                public PaddleDrawingAndroid(Context context) : base(context)
                {
                    var paint = new Paint();
                    paint.SetARGB(255, 200, 255, 0);
                    paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
                    paint.StrokeWidth = 4;

                    _shape = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
                    _shape.Paint.Set(paint);

                    _shape.SetBounds(20, 20, 300, 200);
                }

                protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
                {
                    _shape.Draw(canvas);
                }
            }
        }
```

The Activity:

```
namespace Pong.Droid.Views
{
    [Activity(Label = "!PONG!", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape)]
    public class GamePlayView : MvxActivity
    {
        private GamePlayViewModelAndroid _vm;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.GamePlayView);

            _vm = new GamePlayViewModelAndroid();
            DataContext = _vm;

            AddContentView(new PaddleDrawingAndroid(this), null);
        }
    }
}
```

The layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            local:MvxBind="Text TotalFramesBeenHad" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);


        SetContentView(new PaddleDrawingAndroid(this))\\have you tried this?

    }
```